# Spacy entity linking: wiki dataset not connected

Tags: spacy, graph-databases, wikidata, entity-linking

This relates to the Spacy entity linking library: https://github.com/egerber/spaCy-entity-linker

When I use the following code:

```
    # python -m spacy_entity_linker "download_knowledge_base"
    import spacy
    nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")
    nlp.add_pipe("entity_linker", last=True)
    doc = nlp("I watched the Pirates of the Caribbean last silvester")
    all_linked_entities = doc._.linkedEntities

    for sent in doc.sents:
        sent._.linkedEntities.pretty_print()
```

I get: ValueError: [E139] Knowledge base for component 'entity_linker' is empty. Use the methods `kb.add_entity` and `kb.add_alias` to add entries.

I might need to add the downloaded knowledge base somewhere but it is nowhere stated.

The original code states that add.pipe should be (entity linking has a different name):
`nlp.add_pipe("entityLinker", last=True)`

But then i get the error:
ValueError: [E002] Can't find factory for 'entityLinker' for language English (en). This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a custom component name that's not registered on the current language class

Where are things going wrong?

installed the correct libraries

```
# pip install spacy-entity-linker
# python -m spacy_entity_linker "download_knowledge_base"
```

also have Spacy, the language model, python 3.8.

Answer (score 0):

The SpaCy entity linker library assumes that you have spacy itself configured. As described [here](https://spacy.io/usage#quickstart), you need to install a language core:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I did download the relevant language model, as I am able, without error, to load it here:  '''nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md")'''. I can also perform other spacy tasks that require a language model, just not entity linking.